# openapi 3.0 implemented in mule 4.4 not enforcing path parameter

Tags: mule, openapi

I am using open api 3.0 . I am designing a endpoint which has a path param :
implemented spec in mule 4.4

```
paths:
  
  /comps/{compId}/emps/{empId}:
    get:
      parameters:
      - name: compId
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
          minLength: 1
      - name: empId
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
          minLength: 1
```

However if I make the following request ,  ( notice that 'compId' is a empty string with a space )
it is not getting validated ?
I am sure this should be possible in openapi to enforce not null not empty string ?

```
http://localhost:8081/v2/comps/ /emps/123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your expectation is incorrect. An empty string ("") and an a string containing a space (" ") are two different things. In most programming languages the string containing a single space will be considered a perfectly valid string of length 1.

If you want to add a validation to avoid that you may be able use a `pattern` property for the string and declare a regular expression to validate valid strings. For example something like: `"pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$"`.

Comment: thanks this definitely helps , wondering if the spec should support something like 'notNullOrEmpty' attribute which would be more easily understandable and readable . This definitely helps , my only grips is that regex is not readable easily !